# Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know this question had already a lot of answer and fix...But nothing worked for me...

I'm trying to add the push notification to my android apps. In order to do that, I use the "google-play-services_lib" and the "google-play-services.jar". I followed the tutorial provided by Google [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for Eclipse.

What I did :

- Installing the Google play services with the SDK Manager in Eclipse
- Import an Existing Android Code into Workspace (/android-sdks/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib), with the "Copy projects into workspace" checked...Based on what google suggested

  > Note: You should be referencing a copy of the library that you copied to your development workspace—you should not reference the library directly from the Android SDK directory.
- Referencing the library into my project (Right Click -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add -> google-play-services_lib)
- Added a copy of the google-play-services.jar into my projetc libs folder.
- Adding the jar file to my build path...I had to uncheck the jar files under the Order and export tab to avoid the following error :

  > [2014-07-14 09:41:56 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/a;
  >   [2014-07-14 09:41:56 ] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/a;
- Added the following to my Manifest file :

  ```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  ```
- Creating the pro guard exception

  ```
  -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
  protected Object[][] getContents();
  }

  -keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
   public static final *** NULL;
   }

   -keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
   -keepclassmembernames class * {
   @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
   }

   -keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final ** CREATOR;
   }
  ```

When i try to simply check if the device have the Google Play Service APK with the following

```
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
```

I always see this error :

```
Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.example.testpush.MainActivity.onCreate
```

And :

```
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at com.example.testpush.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-14 10:34:53.631: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Am I missing something here????
Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Is your `<meta-data>` tag under the `<application>` tag in the Manifest file?

Does it improve if the lib isn't in the libs folder?

Comment: I face the same problem !

Comment: I solved the problem with a fresh SDk installation

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same problem. Started clean eclipse workspace (using ADT 23.0.3.1327240). Downloaded the latest Play Services library (v 5.0.89-000) via SDK Manager. Followed all correct [instructions](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), ans still got linker problems when app is launched.

My solution was to use an older version of Play Serices library (luckily still had v4.4.52-000 of the lib in one of my older projects. [Download mine here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22456079/post%20files/SO/24732568/google-play-services_lib_4.x.zip).)  Doing a refresh and clean build after importing this older version seems to solve the problem for now.

Hopefully someone will comment on the [logged bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76190&thanks=76190&ts=1410791901) and give us a real solution.

Comment: Having the same problem here. So it seems to be a problem with the latest jar release..