# Execution failed for task `':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'. > com/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/AbstractSafeParcelable`

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Does anyone know what this issue may be?   I tried checking dependencies and making sure SDK is updated but I just cannot figure out what is missing.

`Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'. > com/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/AbstractSafeParcelable`

Frankly, I have no clue and not sure what to check.  I am configuring Google sign in for a react native app which has configurations in Android studio and uses Google play services.    Trying to run on emulator and I get this error on deploying to simulator.   It built fine beforehand but will not deploy to simulator and I tried a few different ones.

How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to try to disable the **Instant Run** option in Android Studio preview as suggested in [Android Studio 2.0 Preview: ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug' FAILED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059352/android-studio-2-0-preview-apptransformclasseswithinstantrunfordebug-failed) and [App won't run under Android Studio 2.0, after upgrading from 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511018/app-wont-run-under-android-studio-2-0-after-upgrading-from-1-5)

Comment: In addition to that, this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732568/could-not-find-method-com-google-android-gms-common-googleplayservicesutil) might also help.